# JavaScript: Unbale to get value from form

Tags: javascript

I was trying to make javascript take value from textbox and alert it, but it always pops up "Undefined". I tried grabing the value of selected items from combobox, but still shows undefined.
When I try using js in simple webpage, it works. Maybe something wrong with my code.

Note: I want the value to popup when "Schedule" button is clicked. Js will take value from txtbox and selected time value. But it does not..

Code: index.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>Pinterest Grabber</title>
        <style>
            html, body{
                width: 100%;
                background-color: #DADADA;
                color: black;
                font-family: georgia, sans-serif, arial;
            }

        .container{
            background-color: white;
            width: 95%;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #333;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 2px;
        }

        .setupForm{
            background-color: #ff9;
            margin: 10px;
        }

        .pinterestForm{
            background-color: #ff9;
            margin-top: 2%;
        }

        .formTxtbox{
            margin-bottom: 1%;
            border: none;
            width: 75%;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 17px;
            height: 30px;
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            transition-property: box-shadow;
            transition-duration: 0.3s; 
        }

        .formTxtbox:hover{
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #cab;
        }

        .formButton{
            margin-bottom: 1%;
            border: none;
            background-color: royalblue;
            color: white;
            padding: 7px 35px;
            font-size: 17px;
            transition-property: background-color, box-shadow, color;
            transition-duration: 0.3s; 
        }

        .formButton:hover{
            background-color: lime;
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
            color: black;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .txtboxSmall{
            margin-bottom: 1%;
            border: none;
            width: 50%;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 17px;
            height: 30px;
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            transition-property: box-shadow;
            transition-duration: 0.3s; 
        }

        .txtboxSmall:hover{
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #cab;
        }

        .scheduleContainer{
            background-color: #FF9800;
        }

        #scheduleOptions{
            border: none;
            width: 5%;
            height: 30px;
        }

    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.setupForm').hide();

        $("#btnSettingsToggle").click(function(){
            $(".setupForm").toggle('fast');
        });

    });

    // js
    var interval;
    var time = document.getElementById('txtScheduleInterval').value;
    var timeOptions = document.getElementById("scheduleOptions").value;

    function schedule()
    {
        alert(time);
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1 align="center">Pinterest Grabber</h1>
        </header>

        <button class="formButton" id="btnSettingsToggle">Settings</button>

        <center>
        <form action="setup.php" method="post" class="setupForm">
            <h2>Settings</h2>
            <input class="formTxtbox" type="text" name="condapath" placeholder="Your Anaconda Path"><br>
            <input class="formTxtbox" type="text" name="envname" placeholder="Enviroment Name To Activate"><br>
            <input class="formButton" type="submit" value="Save Settings">
        </form>
        </center>
        <?php
            $settings = file('settings.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
            echo "<b>Working Path:</b> " . $settings[0] . '<br>';
            echo "<b>Working Environment:</b> " . $settings[1] . '<br>';
        ?>

        <center>
        <form action="pinterest.php" method="post" class="pinterestForm">
            <h2 align="left" style="margin-top:1%;margin-left:1%;">Pinterest Single</h2>
            <input class="formTxtbox" type="text" name="singleSearchTerm" placeholder="Enter Search Term (EX: old kl)"><br>
            <input class="formTxtbox" type="text" name="singleFilename" placeholder="Enter Filename (EX: data.csv)"><br>
            <input class="formButton" type="submit" value="Start" name="btnPinSingle">
        </form>

        <form action="#" method="post" class="pinterestForm">
            <h2 align="left" style="margin-top:1%;margin-left:1%;">Pinterest Bulk</h2>
            <input class="formTxtbox" type="text" name="listPath" placeholder="Enter List Path (EX: c:\folder\list.txt)"><br>
            <input class="txtboxSmall" type="text" id="txtScheduleInterval" placeholder="Enter Schedule Time">
            <select id="scheduleOptions">
                <option value="secs">Seconds</option>
                <option value="mins">Minutes</option>
                <option value="hrs">Hours</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="formButton" onclick="schedule(); return false;">Schedule</button>
            <input class="formButton" type="submit" value="Start Now" name="btnPinBulk">
        </form>
        </center>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the hosted code on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnt0crs8/1/

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch textbox values in on click function call and try

```
function schedule()
{
    var time = document.getElementById('txtScheduleInterval').value;
    alert(time);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! As other answers suggested too, I think it happens because the time var is not set when the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `time` is now set only once, when the page is loaded.

It should be set whenever the schedule button is pressed.

So move the line `var time = ...` to a place within the schedule function:

```
function schedule()
{
    var time = document.getElementById('txtScheduleInterval').value;
    alert(time);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the below lines into the javascript schedule function

`time = document.getElementById('txtScheduleInterval').value;`

The value of the variable time is getting initialized while the page is getting loaded . While the page is been loaded the value return by `document.getElementById('txtScheduleInterval').value` is `undefined` as the input field txtScheduleInterval has no value in it. So while calling the function schedule you have to make sure that the variable time has the current value in txtScheduleInterval.

Hope this helps you..

Answer (score 0):

You put your javascript which contain dom-operation before your html.

When your "var time = document.getElementById('txtScheduleInterval').value;" ran, it could not get your dom as your expectation. So the solution is either put your script after body or do dom-operation in your schedule function

Comment: Thats right. I put it in the function and it worked. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

fetch the values when the function is called. It should work!

```
function schedule()
        {
            time = document.getElementById('txtScheduleInterval').value;
            timeOptions = document.getElementById("scheduleOptions").value;
            alert(time);
        }
```